# Wrong values with using gpu.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, tensorflow, gpu, gpu.js

I use my code in modes 'dev', 'gpu' and 'cpu'. When I run up my code in 'dev' mode I had right number of results word 'more' in almost 100mb file. There is 259200 words 'more'. But when I run it up in 'gpu' or 'cpu' mode, I have only 3 results from entire file. And second thing, even if I used 'gpu' and 'cpu' mode there is a time differences. When I used gpu it finish in 4000-4100ms and when I use cpu it finish in 2600-2700ms. I think using gpu should be faster than cpu in this searching. Hope for help!

```js
const { GPU } = require('gpu.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

const gpu = new GPU({ mode: 'cpu' });

rl.question('Wprowadż szukaną frazę: ', (value) => {
  let phrase = value;
  let start = new Date();

  fs.readFile('plik2.txt', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
    let tempPhraseLen = phrase.length;
    let tempDataLen = data.length;
    let tempPhrase = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < tempPhraseLen; i++) {
      tempPhrase.push(phrase[i].charCodeAt(0));
    }
    let tempData = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < tempDataLen; i++) {
      tempData.push(data[i].charCodeAt(0));
    }

    function kernelFunction(pFunc, arrFunc, pLen, arrLen) {
      let done = false;
      let counter = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < arrLen; i++) {
        if (arrFunc[i] === pFunc[0]) {
          let isChosen = true;
          let k = 0;
          for (let j = i; j < i + pLen; j++) {
            isChosen = true;
            if (arrFunc[j] !== pFunc[k]) {
              isChosen = false;
              break;
            }
            k++;
          }
          if (isChosen) {
            done = true;
            counter++;
          }
        }
      }
      if (!done) {
        return 0;
      } else {
        return counter;
      }
    }
    const kernel = gpu.createKernel(kernelFunction, {
      output: [ 1 ],
      tactic: 'precision'
    });

    const result = kernel(tempPhrase, tempData, tempPhraseLen, tempDataLen);

    if (result[0] === 0) {
      console.log('Nie udało się znaleźć podanego wzorca');
    } else {
      console.log('Znalazłeś ' + result[0] + ' powtórzeń/nia frazy "' + phrase + '"');
    }
    let end = new Date() - start;
    console.info('Time: %dms', end);
  });
  rl.close();
});
```

Comment: Using the GPU to search for a text string in a 100mb file is not a good use of the GPU.  The GPU is designed for matrix math, providing hundreds if not thousands of floating point processors that run in parallel.  The concept being that an array of floating point numbers are copied to the GPU, and then the kernel performs a defined calculation on each GPU for each value in the array in parallel... Iterating over a string character by character does not leverage the power behind the GPU...

Comment: And 'dev' mode is working because that's simply a GPU.js simulation.  From https://github.com/gpujs/gpu.js/, "This [dev] mode does not actually 'compile' (parse, and eval) a kernel, it simply iterates on your code."